# How automatically loads attributes marked as OwnsOne for a navigational attribute using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My sample data is organized like this:

Each `Custumer` has many `Location` and each `Location` **owns one** `Address`. This schema is organized on model creation as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customers>().HasMany(c => c.Location)...
modelBuilder.Entity<Locations>().OwnsOne(l => l.Address)...
```

When I query a `Location`, the `Location` automatically includes the `Address` (as expected).

```
var location =  myContext.Locations.First(); // Address is populated
```

in other words, I don't need to add `.Include(c => c.Address)` to my query.

However when my query starts querying `Costumer`

```
var c = myContext.Customers.Include(c => c.Location);  // Address is not populated
```

the `Locations` doesn't includes the `Address`. Then I must add `.ThenInclude(c => c.Address)` to the query. That is not expected. Then i need to write down...

```
var c = myContext.Customers.Include(c => c.Location).ThenInclude(c => c.Address);
```

Is that an expected behaviour or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're hitting bug [#9210](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9210). This will be fixed in EF Core version 2.1.0.